# Как отправить JSON ответ вместо php редиректа?

Tags: javascript, php

Привет ситуация следующая, после отправки форм, есть скрипт редиректа

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/contact/success'));
```

Каким образом можно него отправить json код, что бы вместо редиректа у меня выполнялся скрипт на открытие попапа. Спасибо

Comment: Какой у Вас фреймворк?

Answer (score 0):

Отправка JSON из PHP осуществляется следующим образом:

```
echo json_encode([
    'success' => true, //это нужно чтобы подтвердить на стороне клиента что сервер дал верный ответ
    'link' => 'information/contact/success' //пример передачи значения
], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); die;
```

Comment: Если для ответа используется `$this->response`, значит вывод через `echo` / `print` - путь не верный.

Comment: @IvanDudarev это код редиректа, а речь идёт о скрипте на открытие попапа. Каким образом мы будем открывать попап из PHP? Если использовать PHP для отображения самого попап - будет выполняться перезагрузка страницы. Этот вариант нам не подходит, но для вывода попапа в условии сказано что нужен PHP который отправляет JSON код. Пример, который я прикрепил - ответ как отправить при помощи PHP JSON код. Соответственно, когда к серверу приходит запрос с клиента, он отдаёт этот JSON, и клиент уже его парсит и делает то, что необходимо.

Comment: Код редиректа лежит в методе `redirect()` объекта `$this->response`. Этот объект может иметь метод  `json()`, в который достаточно передать массив. В общем, нужно изучать объект `response`. А `echo ... die;` может нарушить работу приложения.